# Move header left to right on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two headers

```
<section>
    <header class="col-lg-9">
        <!-- some content -->
    </header>
    <header class="col-lg-3">
        <!-- some content -->
    </header>
</section>
```

The first header appears on left, and second appears on right normally. Because of that in mobile first header appears first, after scrolling second header appears.

Basically I want to shift the second header on left and first header on right in mobile view. (Max 991px). So that second header will appear first and then first header will appear in mobile view.

Comment: Hello, depending on how is built your header, I would recommend you to use flexbox. You can play with the order in your media query. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/order

Answer (score 4):

You can use Bootstrap's native [column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) to accomplish this.

Example:

```
<section>
    <header class="col-lg-9 col-sm-push-9">
        <!-- some content -->
    </header>
    <header class="col-lg-3 col-sm-pull-3">
        <!-- some content -->
    </header>
</section>
```

Comment: Because OP wants this only to occur on mobile, would this not require the use of a JS to add these classes at a certain window size?

Comment: @Santi not necessarily. I'm assuming OP is using Bootstrap (the class naming conventions mirror Bootstrap 3) - this is all handled via CSS media queries in the framework.

Comment: Oh, duh, not sure why I was thinking that those other classes would modify at *all* sizes! Good call!

Comment: @Santi This is all reliant on my assumption being correct, but I feel like it's an accurate one in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Use Bootstrap column ordering like this...

```
<section>
    <header class="col-lg-3 col-lg-push-9">
        col 3
    </header>
    <header class="col-lg-9 col-lg-pull-3">
        col 9
    </header>
</section>
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/ev3iyxTi8M